# Strange issue with self-referential belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm having a very irritating issue with a self-referential `belongs_to` association in Rails 3:

```
class Locale < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent_locale, :class_name => 'Locale', :foreign_key => 'parent_locale_id'
end
```

In console:

```
locale = Locale.find(2)
locale.parent_locale = Locale.find(3)
locale.save
#----> Association is saved correctly!
locale.parent_locale_id
 => 3
locale.parent_locale
#----> Association is returned correctly!
# Now let's retrieve the record again, and see if it still works...
locale = Locale.find(2)
locale.parent_locale_id
 => 3
locale.parent_locale
 => nil
```

What **on earth** could be the issue here? Any suggestions?

**Edit**: This does not work either:

```
belongs_to :parent_locale, :class_name => 'Locale', :foreign_key => 'parent_locale_id', :inverse_of => :child_locales    
has_many :child_locales, :class_name => 'Locale', :foreign_key => 'parent_locale_id', :inverse_of => :parent_locale
```

**Edit**: I enabled SQL query logging in the console and noticed what happens when I try to retrieve the `parent_locale`:

```
locale.parent_locale
Phrase Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `phrases`.* FROM `phrases` WHERE `phrases`.`key` = 'parent_locale_id' LIMIT 1
 => nil
```

Whoa, what is this? It turns out that `Locale` has the following method:

```
def [](key)
  if phrase = Phrase.find_by_key(key)
    t = self.translations.find_by_phrase_id(phrase.id)
    t.text if t
  end
end
```

Still, how do I make sure this method is not triggered, but the association instead? Frankly, I don't even know why this method is called, as I'm not treating the locale as an array anywhere. Also, there are other associations on this class that **do** work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. The culprit was that the `[]` method was overwritten in the model, and Rails seems to use it to access the model's foreign key column.

I had to change this..

```
def [](key)
  if phrase = Phrase.find_by_key(key)
    t = self.translations.find_by_phrase_id(phrase.id)
    t.text if t
  end
end
```

to this:

```
def [](key)
  if phrase = Phrase.find_by_key(key)
    t = self.translations.find_by_phrase_id(phrase.id)
    t.text if t
  else
    super(key)
  end
end
```

Sorry, you guys could not have guessed this of course.

Answer (score 1):

```
belongs_to :parent_locale, :class_name => 'Locale', :foreign_key => 'parent_locale_id'
has_many :child_locales, :class_name => 'Locale', :foreign_key => 'parent_locale_id'
```

Comment: But the relation is definitifly correct! Tray using other association name and foreign key. Might be a "bad word" in ruby. Could clash with i18n stuff,.. just guessing.

Comment: Maybe its the class name I had strange problems when I named a class "Image".

Comment: Okay sounds stupid but are you sure that you have a column in your database named "partent_locale_id"?^^

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the second find may be hitting ActiveRecord's cache, which is retrieving the "unedited", cached record, instead of retrieving the updated one from the database.

Also, your association is missing the other end, whether it be `has_many` or `has_one`, which is probably preventing the record from being retrieved when referencing `parent_locale`

**Edit** The two ends of the relation should not use the same foreign key, `belongs_to` should not use `foreign_key`

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem persists even when I restart the console, and therefore reset the cache. The association will always return `nil`, not just for this row, but every row.

Comment: @M.Cypher: you forgot the other end of your association as well

Comment: @M.Cypher: The two ends of the relation should not use the same foreign key, `parent_locale` should use `id`, as it will be looking up the `parent_locale` by its id, not by its `parent_locale_id`

Comment: I think you are mixing up `foreign_key` and `primary_key` here.

Comment: @M.Cypher: I was wrong, but both ends should not use the same foreign key